# The span of sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question that says...

> Describe the set$\left \{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:2y-3z=0 \right \} $ as
>   the span of two nonzero vectors.

This is what I've come up with...

$span((0,3,2),(0,2,3))$

which I got by thinking...
$(x,y,z)=a(0,3,2)+(0,2,3)$
which I believe also satisfies 2y-3z=0 if I'm thinking about this problem correctly. Is this a reasonable way to answer this question? Having the (x,y,z) with only a two span vector is  making me question if I'm understanding how to do this problem correctly.

Comment: Almost correct, except that $x$ can be whatever it wants, so you have to account for the movement of $x$ as well. To do this, the x-components of one of the basis elements has  got to be zero. Make that adjustment, and you are fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $2\cdot 2 - 3\cdot 3 \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation
$$
2y - 3z = 0
$$
describes a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, thus a two-dimensional subspace.

In fact the equation can be interpreted as
$$
(0, 2, -3)^\top \cdot (x,y,z) = 0 
$$
which describes the plane as all vectors orthogonal to a normal vector
$$
n = (0, 2, -3)^\top
$$
So we need to find two vectors from the plane which are linear independent.

We just pick $u_1 = (1,0,0)^\top$, as $n \cdot u_1 = 0$ and construct the other vector as
$$
u_2 = (0, 3, 2)^\top
$$
which leads to $n \cdot u_2 = 0$ as well. So the $u_i$ are in the plane and not on a common line, as can be seen from the different non-zero coordinates.

$$
0 = c_1 u_1 + c_2 u_2 \iff \\
c_1 u_1 = -c_2 u_2
$$
for a non-zero coefficient vector (linear dependent vectors), e.g. $c_1 \ne 0$ would lead to
$$
u_1 = -\frac{c_2}{c_1} u_2
$$

If we had no good idea for $u_2$, we could have used $u_2 = n \times u_1$.